# Here Api: Elevation value is incorrect

Tags: here-api

I am calculating the elevation to obtain a graph with the api of nokia and the value of elevation that is returning me in a point near the sea is of 44.0 (meters?). If I get the elevation of that point from other online map services, it returns me 3 meters. What happens with the value returned by Nokia?

I am using the routing API (https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json) with the following parameters "returnelevation=true&routeAttributes=all&representation=navigation&mode=fastest;car" and the response is the following information.

[image: Captura]

and the json response is this

"shape":[
               "36.8142901,-2.5617902,44.0",
               "36.814338,-2.5617993,44.0",
               "36.8146276,-2.562207,45.0",
               "36.8153036,-2.5631618,49.0",
               "36.8153572,-2.5632262,50.0",
               "36.8154109,-2.5632584,50.0",
               "36.8155181,-2.5632906,51.0",
               "36.8155932,-2.5633442,52.0",
               "36.815722,-2.5636446,56.0",
               "36.8158185,-2.5635159,56.0"
            ],

Comment: Provide api details and code explaining the problem.

Comment: sorry for my english, I have edited the question with more details. In point 1 there is at most a height of 3 meters

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport - Can you share some example code with using elevation graph (top screen image) please? I cannot find any examples for this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I use devxpress control suite to show the graph, but you can use any other, from the height information provided by the Nokia api when you pass the "returnelevation = true" parameter. https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/example-bicycle-route-speed-depends-on-slope.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for raising the issue with us. We have informed our data team to check this. You can also report data discrepancies in https://mapcreator.here.com/

Comment: Hello, have you found something? Thank you